# Intel MKL and JNI : How to add a shared library that ld searches symbols from?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, ld, intel-mkl

I'm trying to use a C++ shared library which I built (`libmine.so`) and uses Intel's MKL library from Java using JNI.

I also created `libminejni.so`, and loaded it from Java code like this:

```java
System.loadLibrary("minejni")
```

However it failed to load one of the MKL library (`libmkl_avx2.so`)

```
<path_to_lib>/libmkl_avx2.so: <path_to_lib>/libmkl_avx2.so:
undefined symbol: mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8
```

The symbol is defined in `libmkl_gnu_thread.so`

```
>nm <path_to_lib>/libmkl_gnu_thread.so | grep mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8
00000000004fe240 T mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8
```

So I loaded the library using `System.loadLibrary` before loading the problematic library, but the error wasn't solved.

I executed it with `LD_DEBUG=bindings,symbols`, and found that it didn't search `libmkl_gnu_thread.so` for the symbol.

```
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/local/workspaces/JDK8-1.0/runtime/jdk1.8/bin/java [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/jdk1.8/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib64/libm.so.6 [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib/libmkl_avx2.so [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
     [java]      11275: symbol=mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
     [java]      11275: /lib/libmkl_avx2.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8 (fatal)
```

The library works if I create an executable using C++. I wanted to add `libmkl_gnu_thread.so` to the list of libraries that ld will search symbols, does anybody know how to do that?

NOTE: If I add all MKL related library to LD_PRELOAD, it works but I'm looking for less hacky way.
NOTE2: some paths in the example are modified to remove personal info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JNI library loads objects using by calling [`dlopen` with `RTLD_LOCAL`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (i.e., the default).  This means that the library's symbols do not become available for other `dlopen` calls.  If you call `dlopen` for `libmkl_gnu_thread.so` with `RTLD_GLOBAL` just once inside the same process, it will get injected into the global scope, where other libraries (including those which are loaded using with `RTLD_LOCAL`) can find its symbols.

Alternatively, it should be possible to link `minejni` against `libmkl_gnu_thread.so`, so that it is loaded into the same search scope.  Note that on some distributions, you will have to link with `-Wl,--no-as-neeeded`, to prevent optimizing away this dependency, which appears to be unneeded at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have a follow-up question.
Is there any way to get flags given for a shared library on ```dlopen``` call in a running process?


I linked ```libmkl_gnu_thread.so``` from ```libminejni.so```, and now ```ldd libminejni.so``` shows ```libmkl_gnu_thread.so``` but the ```loadLibrary``` call is still faiing.

I'll try to create a native method to load ```libmkl_gnu_thread.so``` with ```RTLD_GLOBAL``` flag and call it from Java, but it would be nicer if I can avoid creating it.

Comment: Actually I got it resolved. I peek the flags using ```LD_PRELOAD``` and as you said the only flag specified was ```RTLD_LAZY```. I created another function that calls ```dlopen``` with ```RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL``` and now I can load the library. Thanks again for your comment.