# using MKL in cython fails with undefined symbol in shared object from MKL, but direct execution is fine

Tags: cython, ld, intel-mkl, cythonize

I'm writting a physics simulation in C using Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) and want to call it directly from python code using cython.
The cython compilation itself works (program runs error free if MKL is not included in the example) and if I compile my C code directly in gcc with

`gcc -O3 -Wall -m64 -I"${MKLROOT}/include" bar.c -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lpthread -lm -ldl`

it works well. The compiler flags are generated by the [MKL Link line Advisor](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl/link-line-advisor.html).
But If I now try to compile the same code with cython, I'm getting the error message

`INTEL MKL ERROR: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx2.so.1: undefined symbol: mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8. Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so.1 or libmkl_def.so.1.`

I've also tried to compile my program (without the main) into a shared library (`.so`) to get the MKL linking done outside of cython and then just link against that, but after fiddling that library into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I just got the same behavior again.

**Any idea how I can get the linking correct?**

I can swap out the used `cblas_` function for a different one (e.g. `cblas_drot` and some more tried) and get the same error.

I've read quite some other questions (many concerning MKL within anaconda, my MKL is installed manually in `/opt` as the path above shows), including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54694862/intel-mkl-and-jni-how-to-add-a-shared-library-that-ld-searches-symbols-from) which tries to use MKL in java and got the same error.
I can reproduce the same results regarding the `nm` statements (undefined in `libmkl_avx2.so.1`, but defined in `libmkl_gnu_thread.so`), but I failed to apply the answer from that question to my problem. If I try to add `-lmkl_gnu_thread` in the below shown `setup.py` script, I get different unfulfilled dependencies, fixed by also including `-fopenmp` to get back to the old error...

## further information and used files

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/lib/x64:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/lib/emu:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/compiler/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.1.1/env/../lib/intel64/gcc4.8` (set by the mkl setvars script, obtained by `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)
does python maybe do sth weird with this variable?

`readelf -d $MKLROOT/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx2.so.1 | grep NEEDED 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)`  returns `Shared library: [libdl.so.2]`, indicating that it claims to only depend on `libdl` (I don't find the question where I got that command from, but it was also to this topic, just the .1 was missing in the filename)

## used files

### setup.py

(contains a second version as comamnd, can be run like this)

```py
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
#from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
from distutils.core import setup
import numpy

extensions = [
    Extension("foo", ["foo.pyx"],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
        extra_compile_args=["-Wall", "-m64", "-I\"${MKLROOT}/include\""],
        extra_link_args=["-fopenmp", "-L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64", "-Wl,--no-as-needed", "-lmkl_gnu_thread", "-lmkl_intel_lp64",
                         "-lmkl_sequential", "-lmkl_core", "-lpthread", "-lm", "-ldl"])
]

for e in extensions:
    e.cython_directives = {'language_level': "3"} #all are Python-3

# produce the same behaviour, first:
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extensions))
#second
#setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
#      cmdclass = {'build_ext':build_ext})
```

used with
`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

**EDIT** another version with better usage of keywords, according to comments. It gives the same error.

```py
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
from distutils.core import setup
import numpy

extensions = [
    Extension("foo", ["foo.pyx"],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(), "\"${MKLROOT}/include\""],
        libraries=["mkl_intel_lp64", "mkl_sequential", "mkl_core", "pthread", "m", "dl"],
        library_dirs=["${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64"],
        extra_compile_args=["-Wall", "-m64"],
        extra_link_args=["-Wl,--no-as-needed", ])
]

for e in extensions:
    e.cython_directives = {'language_level': "3"} #all are Python-3

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extensions))
```

### foo.pyx

```py
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
import ctypes

cdef extern from "bar.c":  
    void double_elements(int n, double* vec_y)  

def func(np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] y not None):
    double_elements(<int> y.size//2, <double*> <size_t> y.__array_interface__['data'][0])
    
    return y
```

### bar.c

```c
#include <mkl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void double_elements(int n,
                     double* x) {
    cblas_dscal(n, 2., x, 1);
}


#ifndef PY_VERSION_HEX // compile the main only, if not using cython
int main() {
    double x[2] = {1., 2.};
    double_elements(2, x);
    printf("%g %g\n", x[0], x[1]);
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

### run.py

(used for testing, quite boring and only calls the function)

```py
import numpy as np
import foo

x = np.array([1., 2.])
y = foo.func(x)

print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: It is important to pass library paths and libraries in the right order to the linker. Passing them as `extra_link_args` might not work as expected (not sure it is the case here though, but it might be). It is better to use `library_dirs` and `libraries` arguments, see https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension

Comment: @ead I've added a second version of setup.py using the mentioned arguments. I couldn't really make sense of some of them (i.e. `-Wl,--no-as-needed`). Can you confirm that the result is as intended from you? It gives the same error (as I expected, because I previously also tried the completly external compilation as shared library)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by using static linking of MKL instead. Because I also failed to apply all the commands from static linking (it uses groups) in the setup.py script, I've switched to compiling it entirely on my own with

```sh
gcc -O3 -Wall -m64 -I"${MKLROOT}/include" -c bar.c -o build/bar.o

cythonize foo.pyx

# exchange /path/to/numpy/ by value given by numpy.get_include()
gcc -Wall -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -fwrapv -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/path/to/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c foo.c -o build/foo.o -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION

gcc -shared build/foo.o build/bar.o -o foo.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

This corresponds to the compile steps done by the setup script (without checking the change dates) and with some compile flags removed (it used many duplicates).